# why my 301 redirect is not work?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect

I have a blog using wordpress. I changed the domain name, so I want to do 301 redirect for all request.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com$ [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com$ 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.org/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

```
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

The indented three line is new added for the domain name change.

It can only redirect the `old.com` and `www.old.com` to `www.new.org`, but can't redirect `old.com/XXX` to `www.new.org/XXX`.

I think the original rule is conflicted with the new added one. But I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never modify anything between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`. It's just one of those WordPress no-no's. WordPress will overwrite anything between those two entries, so put code above or below it to ensure nothing gets wiped out.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.org/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Does the new rules should be placed betweeen `<IfModule>` and with `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: No, don't modify anything between those two comments. Just place any rules above or below the WordPress block.

Comment: Thank you, but maybe it doesn't work, At last I add a new `<IfModule>` section and add `RewriteEngine On` in it, and it works. The file is in github [.htaccess](https://github.com/ninglee/repository/blob/master/.htaccess).